# Since ${\rm Hom}(G,GL(V))≠0$, what is the purpose of group theory in physics?

Tags: symmetry, group-theory

Given the following 2 facts:

- We can always find a homomorphism between any two groups $G, G'$. It's always ${\rm Hom}(G,G')≠0$.
- Given a vector space, a representation of $G$ is a homomorphism between $G$ and the general linear group of that vector space.

Then what is the point of group representations in physics?
For example: consider a vector space $V_1$ describing something that exist in the physical world.
Suppose this vector space is acted upon by a representation $D$ of the Lorentz group $\mathrm{O}(1,3)$; $D$ maps $\mathrm{O}(1,3)$ to $\mathrm{GL}(V_1)$. We might think that, thanks to this, we can discover some interesting insights concerning the relation between the Lorentz group and our vector space, but... I can always find homomorphism between groups, so I can find a homomorphism between my $\mathrm{GL}(V_1)$ and (for example) $\mathrm{SO}(4)$ or $\mathrm{SU}(2)$. Since any relations that I found between the Lorentz group and $V_1$ was studied through $\mathrm{GL}(V_1)$, I can always say that these relations are actually between $V_1$ and $\mathrm{SU}(2)$... or any other group for that matter. So what did I actually learn from $V_1$?

Maybe I am missing the point of group theory in physics... what do we want to learn from the relation between a group and a vector space?

Comment: Homomorphism is a rather weak notion. Yes there exists a homomorphism between any two groups $G$ and $G'$, just by sending all elements in $G$ to the identity in $G'$. So just saying there exists a homomorphism doesn't mean much.

Comment: If a classical system fulfills a symmetry, say G, then in its quantization one is looking for its representation in the Hilbert space. That's the motivation behind representation theory in physics.

Comment: Adding to Meng Cheng's comment, it might be interesting to point out that "there is a homomorphism between any two groups" is pretty similar to "there is a linear transformation between any two vector spaces"

Comment: Shouldn't your question really be: what is the purpose of representation theory in mathematics?

Comment: please can someone answer my question?

Comment: @TrentKent6 Your question is only 8 hours old. There is no reason to expect that your question will be answered instantaneously. While you are waiting for an answer, I think you would do well to consider Meng Cheng's comment as a road sign to an answer.

Comment: @MengCheng that's the point, it is too weak. i don't get how we can make use of this rather weak notion. Since a representation is weakly defined (only as a homomorphism to GL(V)) and since we can always find a homomorphism between two groups, then what is stopping me from saying that the representation i have in physics from the group SU(2) is actually a representation of SO(3)?

Comment: @TrentKent6 You can always find a homomorphism between two groups, but in physics you are given a particular homomorphism from G to $GL(V)$ as how the physical system you study realizes the symmetry. And usually this homomorphism is a pretty complicated one. So the real question is how to take advantage of this fact. BTW your last sentence is a true statement, if one allows projective representation. And that is because SU(2) is a double cover of SO(3).

Comment: @MengCheng can you clear my mind about how is this homomorphism *given* (as you wrote)? i thought that in physics' group theory you started by observing symmetries of a vector space, i.e. you started with a subgroup of GL(V)... from this point i don't know why we can say with certainty that this subgroup of GL(V) *represents* a specific group G, and *does not represent* any other group (this puzzles me, because representations can always be found from any group G to that GL(V) we have)... so how does nature tell us which representations&groups (G) are correct, and which are not?

Comment: @TrentKent6 OK, I think I understand what your question is really about. I'll try to write an answer below since it's probably not a good idea to have extensive comments.

Comment: ok, looking forward